# if else statement not returning any value if mySQL row is empty?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a social media web app with a blog post page with comment system. On a specific post I can display all rows from the database depending on the post id. However I want to display something which says 'no comments' if there are no rows in relation to the post id. I can't seem to figure out what is returned if no row is present.

```
//Check if there are comments related to post via post id
function comment_exists($post_id, $conn){
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM post_comments WHERE post_id='$post_id'";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1){
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$post_id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM post_comments WHERE post_id = '$post_id' ORDER BY id DESC");


while($row = $sql->fetch_object()){
   $comments[] = $row;
}
foreach($comments as $comment){
   if(comment_exists($post_id, $conn)){
      ?>
      <li class="list-group-item">
         <div class="h6 m-0">@<?php echo "$comment->username" ?></div>
         <div class="text-muted"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o mr-1"></i><?php echo "$comment->comment_time" ?></div>
         <p class="card-text"><?php echo "$comment->comment" ?></p>
      </li>
      <?php
   }else{
      echo 'No comments yet';
   }
}
```

I have 2 posts, one with $post_id=14 with 0 comments, one with $post_id=21 with 4 comments.

For post_id=21, it displays the 4 comments as expected.
For post_id=14, it displays an empty page, not 'no comments yet' from the else statement

Comment: Your `foreach` won't execute any iterations if there are no comments. Given you're running essentially the same query twice, you should refactor your logic to check `count($comments)` instead of running a redundant query. FYI, you'll need to add `$comments = [];` before the `while` loop

Comment: Please be aware that you should **NEVER** use user input (like `$post_id`) directly in SQL statements! You should use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead, binding your `$_GET` variables to parameters. Given your code above, you have a serious security vulnerability -- a malicious user could easily `DROP` your entire database (or possibly even create a backdoor). You can refer to [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) for further information on how to prevent SQL injection in PHP :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I will definitely read up on this more. As this is only a locally hosted project for uni it shouldn't be a huge issue for now, but good to know for future reference :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if `$comments` is empty. You don't need to check every time through the loop, since the loop won't run if there are no comments.

```
if (empty($comments)) {
    echo "No comments yet";
} else {
    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
      ?>
      <li class="list-group-item">
         <div class="h6 m-0">@<?php echo "$comment->username" ?></div>
         <div class="text-muted"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o mr-1"></i><?php echo "$comment->comment_time" ?></div>
         <p class="card-text"><?php echo "$comment->comment" ?></p>
      </li>
      <?php
    }
}
```